# Search in page contents Android application (like find in Chrome for Android)?

Tags: android, google-chrome

I would like to have similar functionality like chrome for finding text in page contents.

Is there any library for this or should I write it from scratch?

[image: Search in chrome app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe is too late, but try to use the BrowserFiP [library](https://github.com/Y-E-P/BrowserFiP)

Answer (score -1):

Well you're in luck there's a SearchView! http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html